# Limit access to multiple keycloak clients. per configuration or token

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, keycloak

I have two clients lets say ClientA and ClientB, and one user called userA  both clients  are access type confidential, and I followed this example to write my services 
https://sandor-nemeth.github.io/java/spring/2017/06/15/spring-boot-with-keycloak.html
and everything is working,
 I have one problem though if I request an access token using this,postman request

```
client_id = ClientA, 
grant_type=password, 
client_secret= 8657c896-b2fw-4ad6-aa9d-72563240cc62, 
scope = openid, 
user =userA
password=passwordA.
```

now when I make a request to my secured endpoint using this token it works as it should, but the problem is if I generate another token using the above body requests,
except change  client_id = ClientB and clientB's secrete and call the same endpoint it will still let me access the endpoint, but I want to limit(prohibit) this, what I want to do is limit the request only to its own resource.

and this is the spring config

```
keycloak:
  realm: spring-security-example
  bearer-only: true
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
  ssl-required: external
  resource: clientA
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
```

so if I generate a token for clientA, token generated by using ClintB should not be allowed to access any endpoints.(and I can see in the JWT field "azp" : "ClientA".) 
how would I go about this, is this could be achieved through the configuration. or I have to do it in the spring boot code?

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        super.configure(http)
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's multiple ways this can be achieved. The method I would use would be to define a role inside each client, which the user has to have to access that client. Then you would check before allowing access to that client that they have that client role.

To create a client role, inside the admin console, choose your "realm", then "Clients" from the left hand menu => select "client2" => select "Roles" => "Add Role", and name it what ever you want. Say "admin".

To grant that role to a user so they can access that client, go to "Users" => Select your user => Role Mappings => Under the client role section select your client => select your new role and assign it to the user.

You then need to limit the scope access from client 1 by going "Clients" => "Client 1" => "Scopes tab" => Uncheck "Full scopes allowed" => select "client 2" from "Client Roles" drop down, and ensure the role isn't applied to this client.

You can now test out wether this user will get access to this role from logging into "client 1" by going to "Clients" => "Client 1" => "Client Scopes" => "evaluate tab". If the client scopes are configured correctly, you shouldn't gain access to client 2 role.

The last piece of the puzzle is configuring your Client to check for this role. On your backend API (or other client side enforcement location), configure keycloak to protect against the newly created client role for that client. For spring boot, I believe it's something like this (I don't use springboot so untested, but taken from their notes here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter) :

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/yourClientRoute").hasRole("admin")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
```